# Action listner to JTable that been reset

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, actionlistener

I'm having issue with Action Listener of a JTable that being updated according the radioButtons.

I created a blank table and just re-update according to which button is selected. 
The only issue I have is that the action Listener are not being updated along with the current table.

For example

Table A
Table B
Table C (only one with action listeners)

If I click through A B it's fine but once I hit C and try going back to A and selecting a row it still performing the action listeners of Table C. Is there a way to remove the action Listeners from a JTable?

Code Looks something along this line

```
JTable table = new JTable();

//Inside buttonActionListener

if (A)
table.setmodel(A);
else if (B)
table.setmodel(B);
else if (C) 
{
table.setmodel(C);
table.addmouselistener(new mouseclick())
}
```

I could just add action listener to all of the table...which defeats the point of me updating them ... but yea is there a way around this?

Comment: `1)` this JButton is inside JTable, `2)` why is in the JTable MouseListener, `3)` whyt's new mouseclick(), `4)` your question is too hard answerable, `5)` post code in http://sscce.org/ form,

Comment: even if showing snippets, post real code, not invented api. Plus keep the snippet somehow related to the verbal description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
public void removeMouseListener(MouseListener l)
```

But something is weird if you need to add and remove listeners all the time... Maybe you'd better have the listener remain but write it so that it checks some kind of condition that verifies its logic should be preformed.

Comment: Yea I think I'll have to put a some switch there to tell if the listener is being used